# Where put "resources" dir on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

My project is a eclipse Java project and it structure is

\Game\src

\Game\resources

But this code returns a exception:

```
image = new ImageIcon(new URL("resources\\Monster.png"));
```

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: resources\Monster.png

What's wrong?

Comment: "resources\\Monster.png" is not an URL. Try "file://resources/Monster.png"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse, make the `resources` folder a Source folder so that it adds the files inside it to the classpath when it launches your application.

Then use

```
image = new ImageIcon(YourClass.class.getResource("/monster.png"));
```

where `YourClass` is your class.

The [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) call

> Finds a resource with a given name.

It does this by looking for it in your application's classpath based on some naming rules described in the javadoc.

Comment: @user1902062 You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it covered everything by checking the checkmark, when you can.