# Where should I put my resources for a Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, project, embedded-resource

I'm programming in Java using Eclipse.

I have recently tried playing a sound file in my program. I did this:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("ih.wav");
audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioIn);
clip.start();
```

This only worked, when I tried to put ih.wav in the bin folder, as if the bin folder was the "base folder" for my project. Putting the file in the main folder of the project, didn't work. Putting it in the src folder, didn't work too.

Can someone explain to me where to put my resources for Java programs? Also, does it matter if I import the resources into Eclipse? Thanks

EDIT:

Tried to create a resources folder in the main project folder, still gives me a NullPointerException:

```
        URL url1 = this.getClass().getResource("res/ah.wav");
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url1);
        clip1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip1.open(audioIn);

        URL url2 = this.getClass().getResource("res/eh.wav");
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url2);
        clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip2.open(audioIn);

        URL url3 = this.getClass().getResource("res/ih.wav");
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url3);
        clip3 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip3.open(audioIn);

        clip1.start();
        clip2.start();
        clip3.start();
```

Comment: Did you recompile after putting it in the src folder? Are you *sure*?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Shouldn't the project folder be the 'base folder' for the project? Why is bin the "starting point"?

Comment: create a `resources` folder like `-- src
    `-- main
        `-- resources

Comment: The bin folder is not the starting point. Eclipse simply compiles everything from the src directory into the bin directory. I would think that putting an image or whatever in the src directory would cause eclipse to copy it to the bin folder. But lick @nachokk said, you can also create a resources folder.. just make sure you tell eclipse to include it in the compilation/building process!

Comment: @nachokk Please make it answer so I can upvote it ;)

Comment: Where should I create this folder? In src or in bin? (Sorry if I'm not following you)

Comment: @user3150201 Don't create anything in bin, everything in there is generated when compiled.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still seems that eclipse doesn't find my files, see my edit please.

Comment: If you are using an IDE make sure the resources are getting moved into the binary directory. They do not update as often as your class files. It can help to clean the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would be to create a folder (depending on your package structure) that is called either `res` or `resources` where you will keep project related resources such as any images or sound files.

Depending on preference, either put this folder in your main project folder `MyProject/res` or put it inside the relevant package, e.g. `main.java.res`

EDIT

To adhere more to your question, I'm not too familiar with the `getResources()` method, so instead I would personally recommend using some code similar to:

```
File file = new File("ih.wav");
audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioIn);
clip.start();
```

That *should* produce the results you are looking for, given that you change the path of he file accordingly (e.g. `"main/resources/ih.wav"` or wherever you are storing the file.

Comment: Tried what you said, doesn't seem to work. Please see my edit.

Comment: Where did you create the folder? keeping in mind you will have to use the path in the parameter of `getResource()`

Comment: I created it in the same folder where src and bin exist. The main folder of the project.

Answer (score 8):

***Caveat**: I don't use Eclipse, I've never used Eclipse, my knowledge of Eclipse amounts to reading other posts and answering questions here*

Under your project, create a directory called `resources`.  In here place all you "resources" you want to access from within your application.  These will be bundled with your application as embedded resources.

From within your application use either

```
this.getClass().getResource("/ah.wav")
```

or

```
this.getClass().getResource("/resources/ah.wav")
```

Assuming that you placed the files at the top level of the `resources` path.  If they're in a sub-directory, you'll need to provide the full path...

Clean, build and test

Answer (score 4):

I'd create a `resources` folder inside `src` something like  `src/main/resources`. You would like to take a look to [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) that is project management and comprehension tool that help a lot in project organization.

Comment: I did exactly that, but for some reason I get a NullPointerException when trying to reach the files :\ Any ideas?

Comment: @user3150201 Well it's always try and error, but see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071614/where-put-resources-dir-on-eclipse) if it helps you

Comment: @user3150201 also make a clean & build